# Fast C++ simplified map\dictionary like collection?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need a simple API

```
int id = Put(value);
void Remove(id);
// and some kind of for_each that could iterate over all data ( there will be around ~1000 objects or less), and this is operation that will be calld super often compared to Put and Remove
```

There [is](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Efficiency%20with%20Algorithms%2C%20Performance%20with%20Data%20Structures/Efficiency%20with%20Algorithms%2C%20Performance%20with%20Data%20Structures%20-%20Chandler%20Carruth%20-%20CppCon%202014.pdf) [extreamly](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Data-Oriented%20Design%20and%20C%2B%2B/Data-Oriented%20Design%20and%20C%2B%2B%20-%20Mike%20Acton%20-%20CppCon%202014.pptx) lot of critisizing talk in many C++ confrences on how std::map is slow. And actually I do not need all of its members any way. So under that impression I look for an alternative that would support my minified needs.

Comment: What have you actually tried, and how much faster does it need to be? (I would expect adding and then removing 1000 elements in std::map would be done in less than 1ms on a modern desktop PC, but of course, if you have a 40MHz microcontroller, it will probably be more than 100ms or so)

Answer (score 2):

It mostly comes down to what characteristics you need/care about. A map provides:

1. unique keys
2. fast lookup by key
3. in-order iteration by key
4. insertion/deletion of arbitrary items
5. order is always maintained

If you don't need all those, you might be better off with some other container. If you don't care about order or uniqueness, then you could just create a vector of int/pointer (or guid/pointer) pairs, and add new pairs as needed. This supports fast iteration, but makes finding an individual item relatively slow and does nothing to maintain uniqueness. If you want ordering at specific times, you can use sort to get that. Likewise, if you want uniqueness at specific times, you can use sort followed by unique to get that. When it's sorted, finding items by key is generally quite fast (usually faster than with `map`).

If you care about uniqueness but don't need the items in order when you iterate them, you might want to consider an unordered_map instead. Like a map, this still lets you find an individual item quickly, but iteration doesn't happen in a meaningful order. Like with a sorted vector, finding an individual item by key is usually faster than with `map`.